# captiva Theme Error

Tags: theme-development

I have Install Captiva in my system local.its showing error like this

Warning: POST Content-Length of 36013235 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
Are you sure you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8388608 bytes is 8M, which is the default post size limit in PHP. Update your `post_max_size` in php.ini to a larger value, may be 50M.

`post_max_size` sets the maximum amount of data that can be sent via a POST in a form.

Comment: Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: changed sir but still same error sir

Comment: Did you restart HTTP server after changing values in `php.ini`?

Comment: no sir i will restart in my xampp server  and i will check sir

Comment: that error fixed sir.Now showing error LIke this                  Could not create directory. Captiva.Responsive.WordPress.WooCommerce.Theme.v1.4.1/ThemeInstall/captiva/admin/redux-framework/ReduxCore/assets/css/vendor/jquery-ui-bootstrap/images

Comment: I am glad it fixed your error. For issue with theme, you should contact theme developer because it could be permission issue or something else.

Comment: Also, please don't forget to accept answer if this solved your issue. Thanks :)

Comment: sure sir accepted

Comment: BTW why are you installing theme that way. Just extract it and upload main theme files via FTP in `/wp-content/themes/` folder on your server.

Comment: i will try that way sir sure

Comment: sir i am using localhost xampp how to use local side FTP?

Comment: In your local WordPress, go to `wp-content/themes` folder and add extracted captiva theme directory.